# Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port

Tags: spring, port

i cloned spring-clinic and package is success

but when i execute jar..

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port...

so i add command server.port=8090 in application.properties.

but nothing change...
Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port...

what can i do?? please help me..

i use window and IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can add `--server.port=9000` in Environment variables in Edit Configuration like so

[image]